# A ListView with a Switch in each row, how to bind the Switch with the item in the row?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In **Xamarin.Forms**:
I have a **ListView** which is being populated with certain objects. In **each of the rows** of the ListView I also have a **Switch**, which the user can use to **select or deselect** that item.

**My problem** is that I can't figure out how to pass the specific item in the ListView to the **toggled event** of the Switch, so that the users' preferences can then be saved.

*i.e. How does each Switch know which object it shares a row with in the ListView?* (In the code below, the objects I am trying to pass are the **Survey** objects.)

**What I found so far:**
I have found this question which is exactly what I am after, but I can't quite understand the answer:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64197/switch-inside-listview-get-listview-item-on-toggle

**Following the post above, I have tried the following:**

Extended the Switch class:

```
public class ListSwitch : Switch
    {
        public static BindableProperty SurveyItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "SurveyItem",
            returnType: typeof(Survey),
            declaringType: typeof(ListSwitch),
            defaultValue: null);

        public Survey SurveyItem
        {
            get { return (Survey)GetValue(SurveyItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SurveyItemProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

Added this to my View codebehind:

```
        mySwitch.SetBinding(ListSwitch.SurveyItemProperty, "SurveyItem");

        mySwitch.Toggled += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var item = (Survey)((ListSwitch)sender).SurveyItem;
            _vm.WatchSurveyCommand.Execute(item);
        };
```

When I try this I get the following **error**:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at ConsensusCloud.MainViewModel+<ExecuteWatchSurveyCommand>c__async1.MoveNext () [0x00033] in /Users/Lambros/Dropbox/XamarinProjects/ConsensusCloud/ConsensusCloud/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs:65
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113
  at ConsensusCloud.MainViewModel+<>c__async6.MoveNext () [0x00021] in /Users/Lambros/Dropbox/XamarinProjects/ConsensusCloud/ConsensusCloud/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs:57
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
  at ConsensusCloud.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/Lambros/Dropbox/XamarinProjects/ConsensusCloud/iOS/Main.cs:17
```

Comment: Have you verified that your (ListSwitch)sender isn't null? And SurveyItem actually has a value? One of those doesn't have a value, which is where your problem resides

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard I have just changed the toggle code to this:

    switchWatch.Toggled += (sender, e) =>
    {
     var item = (Survey)((ListSwitch)sender).Survey;
     if (item != null)
     {
      _vm.WatchSurveyCommand.Execute(item); 
     }
    };
and the Command does not get executed..So it seems (ListSwitch)sender is null

Comment: What is "SurveyItem"? It would have to be a *public property* on the *individual* items that are contained in your list. If you want to access the current item, just bind to ".", which is the current item.

Comment: @Krumelur Thanks for your comment! This is the part of the other post I found which I didn't understand. Does that mean change the binding like this?

'switchWatch.SetBinding(ListSwitch.SurveyItemProperty, ".");'

I'm quite new at this...

Comment: Yeah, that's it. In the ListView, the binding context for the template that is used for the items is the currently processed item. So "." is the item itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "SurveyItem"? It would have to be a *public property* on the *individual items* that are contained in your list's `ItemsSource`. If you want to access the current item, just bind to ".", which is the current item.

In `ListView`, the binding context for the template that is used for the items, is the currently processed item. See the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) for more details on this topic.